# How to handle multiple network statuses by LiveData on MVVM pattern

Tags: android, retrofit, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a problem with MVVM pattern and LiveData. I have a list of questions in recyclerView,  these questions can be answered by user. I use Retrofit to connect with remote server and local db to store my data on device (I am considering Room, Realm or ObjectBox for storing data). Of course I am trying to implement Repository class which will decide from where to take data (remote or local db). Nevertheless I have read a lot of articles about LiveData and handling network status (loading, error and success) but I can't find a good approach to handling multiple status. I need to handle status for:
- sending multiple answer request (loading or error view on every item in recyclerView)
- fetching data (list of questions) from remote server (loading or error view on full screen)
- downloading more data from remote server (infinity scrolling with loading view on the bottom of list or error view)
- refreshing current data (swipe up on the list; snack bar after error occured)
- etc.

I read for example these articles:
https://medium.com/@dmilicic/a-detailed-guide-on-developing-android-apps-using-the-clean-architecture-pattern-d38d71e94029

https://proandroiddev.com/concise-error-handling-with-livedata-and-retrofit-15937ceb555b

https://medium.com/@MinaSamy/android-architecture-components-livedata-7717a626b782

https://medium.com/@eric.maxwell/how-to-use-livedata-with-realm-3e57958b5aa1

https://codinginfinite.com/kotlin-coroutine-call-adapter-retrofit/

https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/magic-with-kotlin-rxjava-and-the-repository-pattern-af751a451254

Could you give me some advices how to handle a lot of network statuses by LiveData and Android Architecture Components ? Do anyone have any experience with this?